# How to expose a c++ function taking variable arguments in boost python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python, variadic-functions

I have a c++ function taking variable number of arguments.

```
   char const* Fun(int num, ...)
   {
   ....//does some processing on the arguments passed
   }
```

Boost Python code for exposing this function is written as,

```
    using namespace boost::python;
    BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( lib_boost )
   {
       def( "Fun", Fun );
   }
```

while compiling this code gives the below error

> In file included from /boost_1_42_0/boost/python/data_members.hpp:15,
>                    from /boost_1_42_0/boost/python/class.hpp:17,
>                    from /boost_1_42_0/boost/python.hpp:18,
>                    from Lib_boost.h:3,
>                    from Lib_boost.cpp:1: /boost_1_42_0/boost/python/make_function.hpp: In function
>   'boost::python::api::object boost::python::make_function(F) [with F =
>   const char* (*)(int, ...)]': /boost_1_42_0/boost/python/def.hpp:82:
>
>   instantiated from 'boost::python::api::object
>   boost::python::detail::make_function1(T, ...) [with T = const char*
>   (*)(int, ...)]' /boost_1_42_0/boost/python/def.hpp:91:   instantiated
>   from 'void boost::python::def(const char*, Fn) [with Fn = const char*
>   (*)(int, ...)]' Lib_boost.cpp:540:   instantiated from here
>   /boost_1_42_0/boost/python/make_function.hpp:104: error: invalid
>   conversion from 'const char* (*)(int, ...)' to 'const char*
>   (*)(int) /boost_1_42_0/boost/python/make_function.hpp:104: error:
>
>   initializing argument 1 of 'boost::mpl::vector2
>   boost::python::detail::get_signature(RT (*)(T0), void*) [with RT =
>   const char*, T0 = int]'

My understanding from the error info above is boost python could not recognize the function taking variable arguments(invalid conversion from 'const char* (*)(int, ...)' to 'const char* (*)(int)')

Exposing a function with fixed/known set of arguments is not the same for functions taking variable arguments.
How to expose a function with variable arguments?

Comment: What are the types of the variadic arguments?  Are they guaranteed to be one single type or can they be heterogeneous?  How do you know what types they are, in order to use them?

Comment: first argument is integer and remaining are heterogenous(number of arguments can also vary)

Comment: So how do you know how to use them?  Note that printf() takes varargs but also a format string which it needs to know how to process the arguments.  Without something like that, you are probably going to have a bad time.

Comment: Actually we are adding boost interface to the existing application n which function is like below
 ` char const* Fun(int num, ...)
 { ....//arguments are captured by va_List
 va_list vl;
 va_start(vl,num);
 //read vl va_end(vl); 
}` 
the example provided in the link shared, function arguments are fixed and type is also fixed.

Comment: suggest me a solution for the case where first argument is integer followed by 'n' number of strings(char *), where n varies from 1 to 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using c++11 then following could work ( tested on g++-4.8.2 )

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/list.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cassert>

using namespace boost::python;

template <int... Indices>
struct indices
{
    using next = indices<Indices..., sizeof...(Indices)>;
};

template <int N>
struct build_indices
{
    using type = typename build_indices<N-1>::type::next;
};

template <>
struct build_indices<0>
{
    using type = indices<>;
};
template <int N>
using BuildIndices = typename build_indices<N>::type;

template <int num_args>
class unpack_caller
{
private:
    template <typename FuncType, int... I>
    char * call(FuncType &f, std::vector<char*> &args, indices<I...>)
    {
        return f(args.size(), args[I]...);
    }

public:
    template <typename FuncType>
    char * operator () (FuncType &f, std::vector<char*> &args)
    {
        assert( args.size() <= num_args );
        return call(f, args, BuildIndices<num_args>{});
    }
};

//This is your function that you wish to call from python
char * my_func( int a, ... )
{
    //do something ( this is just a sample )
    static std::string ret;

    va_list ap;
    va_start (ap, a);
    for( int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
    {
        ret += std::string( va_arg (ap, char * ) );
    }

    va_end (ap);
    return (char *)ret.c_str();
}

std::string my_func_overload( list & l )
{
    extract<int> str_count( l[0] );
    if( str_count.check() )
    {
        int count = str_count();
        std::vector< char * > vec;
        for( int index = 1; index <= count; ++index )
        {
            extract< char * > str( l[index] );
            if( str.check() )
            {
                //extract items from list and build vector
                vec.push_back( str() );
            }
        }
        //maximum 20 arguments will be processed.
        unpack_caller<20> caller;

        return std::string( caller( my_func, vec ) );
    }

    return std::string("");
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    def("my_func", my_func_overload )
    ;
}
```

In python:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import my_module as m
>>> m.my_func([5, "my", " first", " five", " string", " arguments"])
'my first five string arguments'
>>>
```

In this example "char * my_func( int a, ... )" simply concatenates all the string arguments and returns the resulting string.

Answer (score 2):

I find the best way to treat variadic arguments is by using `raw_function`.  This way you get full control in converting your C++ parameters into Python objects:

The wrapper:

```
using namespace boost::python;

object fun(tuple args, dict kwargs)
{
    char* returned_value;

    for(int i = 0; i < len(args); ++i) {
        // Extract the args[i] into a C++ variable,
        // build up your argument list
    }

    // build your parameter list from args and kwargs 
    // and pass it to your variadic c++ function

    return str(returned_value);
}
```

The declaration:

```
def("fun", raw_function(fun, 1) );
```

`raw_function` takes two arguments:  the function pointer and minimum number of arguments.

Comment: // build your parameter list from args and kwargs 
// and pass it to your variadic c++ function How would you do this?

Comment: @Icarus3: if your variadic function has no version taking va_list (like vprintf instead of printf), you will be stuck implementing one wrapper function in C++ for each individual combination of arguments passed to the variadic function.  Or you will have to write the assembly yourself to call the variadic function.  If you want the nasty details, try reading this: http://gallium.inria.fr/~rainey/articles/ml-varargs.pdf  Or try using libffi which may help you do the same but without writing assembly yourself: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/03/04/flexible-runtime-interface-to-shared-libraries

Comment: Thanks for comment. Seems like a nice read (pdf). I was thinking on a line of using variadic template function as a wrapper and then using std::forward to call C-variadic function. The challenge was to use boost::bind and indexes ( tie the arguments ) to call my variadic template.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it by treating the arguments as optional, so long as you know what the maximum count can be.  See here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/FunctionOverloading