# How to expose Variadic Template arguments member function to boost python?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, boost-python

I have class member methods(omitting class definition itself):

```
    template<Severity level, typename...Args>
    void print(Args...args){  //VA template print function which calls recursively print_impl

        d_policy->lockMutex();
        switch(level){
            case DEBUG :
                d_policy->getBuffer() << "<DEBUG>";
                break;
            case WARNING :
                d_policy->getBuffer() << "<WARNING>";
                break;
            case ERROR :
                d_policy->getBuffer() << "<ERROR>";
                break;
        }
        d_policy->getTime();
        print_impl(args...);
    }

        template<typename First, typename...Rest>
        void print_impl(First first, Rest...rest){  //Called by print_impl public method
        }

        void print_impl(){
        }
```

I'm stuck in wrapping it into boost python, I saw thread in stack overflow how to wrap variable arguments function but it is different beast: [How to expose a c++ function taking variable arguments in boost python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952140/how-to-expose-a-c-function-taking-variable-arguments-in-boost-python), any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does that not answer your question?  When you tried it what went wrong?

Comment: How would You put `print(Args...args)` which is a template as template template-parameter in `return std::string( caller( my_func, vec ) );` ?

Comment: Oh, you just don't know how to create a single object that reprents an entire overload set!  `auto print_overloads = [](auto&&...args){return print( decltype(args)(args)... );};` then pass `print_overloads` in place of `my_func`?  Well, with maybe some work for the `this` depending.